# Storing complex objects through stored procedures

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, jdbc, jdbctemplate

I have a complex object which includes multiple objects through composition.
What is a recommended way to persist such an object into database?

```
User{
name:
DOB:
address:{
street:
zipcode:
}
accounts:[
{accountId:"",bank:""},
{accountId:"",bank:""}
]
...
}
```

Do note the collections which form part of the object.
This entity would map to multiple tables in the database - user,address,account....

What is the recommended way to interact with a stored procedure for this kind of a data structure?

Comment: Pass the information to the stored procedure as XML and store it either in XML or normalize it into multiple tables. Is one option.

Comment: Could you help with an example of the case where data is sent in as xml and stored into multiple tables

Answer (score 0):

You have two options.

You can send the data as xml to your server and directly save this into an xml column.

You can store it in an `nvarchar` column with a specified limit (e.g. `nvarchar(1000)`) if possible. Otherwise store it into an `nvarchar(max)` as it will be directly readable. A conversion to `varbinary` or something like that won't be useful.